# Converting hive query to Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive query which runs in map-reduce mode per day. The total processing time takes 20 mins which is fine as per our daily process.
I am looking to execute in spark-framework.

To begin with, I have set the execution engine=spark in the hive shell and executed the same query.

The process had transformations and actions and the whole query completed around 8 mins. This query has multpile subqueries, IN Clauses and where conditions.
The question is, how does the spark-environment creates RDDs complex queries(Assume that I have just run the same query as in hive).Does it create RDD for each subqueries?

Now I would want to leverage spark-sql in place of the hive query. How should we approach these kind of complex where in we have lot of subqueries and aggregations involved.
I understand that for relational data computations, we need to leverage data frames.

Would this be a right approach in re-writing them in spark-sql or hold on to the thing which is setting the execution engine = spark and running the hive query.
In case if there are advantages in writing the queries in spark-sql and running on the spark, what would be the advantages.

For all the subqueries and various filter and aggregation logics,what would be performance for data frame APIs.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for ... It's been documented that Dataframe operations and a written out SQL query compile down into the same Spark operations

Comment: FWIW, have you tried using Tez execution mode instead? Assuming you have it installed? Under no circumstances, would I be using Hive in mapreduce mode at all

Comment: No I haven't. This is for a PoC approach just I am thinking. Would it be a right approach  in writing the hive sql query in spark-sql format by creating data frames and building the logic? Will there be any significant performance improvement? Assuming in the one single hive query, we don't know how data frames will be created and we wont have any control right.

Comment: Again, In Spark, a Dataframe operation has no performance improvement over a `SparkSession.sql` execution. Both should create the same query plan

Comment: So, can I assume that writing the same query by setting hive engine=spark and re-writing the same query in spark-sql gives the same performance stats.?

Comment: I'm not sure how Hive's Spark engine works, and was under the impression that it's still not considered production grade. Feel free to try SparkSQL out for yourself. All I'm saying is that you don't really need to translate everything into the Dataframes API if you already have a working query